# Flex sizing messing up when text is too long

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css, size

I'm wrinting a digital menu for a restaurant using tailwind so i have this

```
`<div class="flex gap-2 m-4 items-center">
    <h3 class="text-lg font-semibold my-2 leading-5">Hamburger</h3>
    <div class="grow bg-violet-950 h-0.5"></div>
    <p>$8.99</p>
 </div>
<p class="ml-5 mr-16 -mt-4 text-sm text-justify">Served with tomato, letuce and french fries</p>`
```

So far so good, but when i have an item with a larger name (lets asy Cheeseburger with pineapple and bacon), then the h3 occupies all of the width of the row but the price and i no longer have a line (the div with the grow class) to show up even though the h3 text wraped to a second line and should be smaller. Or shouldn't it? how can i properly size my elemnts here?

I tried adding the max-width-2/33 (is set to 70%) to force the h3 to pull back and i got a bit of a line with this walk around, but i would like to make the h3 to just occupy the 2 text lines lenght so the div line is longer. I don't mind the text being in 2 lines.

```
`<div class="flex gap-2 m-4 items-center">
    <h3 class="text-lg font-semibold max-w-2/33 my-2 leading-5">Hamburger</h3>
    <div class="grow bg-violet-950 h-0.5"></div>
    <p>$8.99</p>
 </div>
<p class="ml-5 mr-16 -mt-4 text-sm text-justify">Served with tomato, letuce and french fries</p>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the h3 occupies all of the width of the row but the price and i no longer have a line (the div with the grow class) to show up even though the h3 text wraped to a second line and should be smaller. Or shouldn't it?

The `<h3>` element will take up as much width as it can, then any text that overflows would wrap. The width of the `<h3>` then *doesn't* "backtrack" to the width where the wrapping occurs.

You could consider setting a `flex-basis` on the line element to give it an equivalent of a "minimum width" to display:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div class="w-96">
  <!-- before -->
  <div class="flex gap-2 m-4 items-center">
      <h3 class="text-lg font-semibold my-2 leading-5">Cheeseburger with pineapple and bacon</h3>
      <div class="grow bg-violet-950 h-0.5"></div>
      <p>$8.99</p>
   </div>
  <p class="ml-5 mr-16 -mt-4 text-sm text-justify">Served with tomato, letuce and french fries</p>

  <!-- after -->
  <div class="flex gap-2 m-4 items-center">
      <h3 class="text-lg font-semibold my-2 leading-5">Cheeseburger with pineapple and bacon</h3>
      <div class="grow bg-violet-950 h-0.5 basis-40"></div>
      <p>$8.99</p>
   </div>
  <p class="ml-5 mr-16 -mt-4 text-sm text-justify">Served with tomato, letuce and french fries</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This relly helps, downside is I have to change the basis value in every item but works like a charm